# Unit test in aptana studio 3

Tags: python, class, unit-testing, testing, aptana

How do you run a Unit test on your class creation in aptana studio 3 on a python format class.
I am wondering if I am supposed to add something to my code or is there a function in aptana studio that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio does not have a special test mode like PyCharm does, if you want to run unit-tests, you will simply need to create a `unittest` using Python's `unittest` module. So, for example:

```
import unittest


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And now, simply run this script.

Answer (score 0):

Just righ-click the test file and select `Run As` -> `Python unit-test` for the first time, on subsecuent runs just press `CTL + F11`